# how to create a table using <div> tag without using dispaly:table

Tags: css

Can any one help me to draw a table with div tag and without using display:table property in asp.net mvc3.

I want to create this table dynamically with borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a proper table for tabular data, you should not try and use divs to create it. Use tables.

Comment: i need to create table using div only ... is it possible